# How do I control how often search engines visit my site?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines

I've been using the following line in the `<head>` of my sites for years:

`<meta name="revisit-after" content="3 days" />`

I recently discovered that it's not one of [the meta tags](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812) that Google understands, which I take to mean that there's no point in including it, and that it's been doing no good at all for years.

**How often do search engines crawl a website by default, and what reliable ways are there to increase or decrease that frequency?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [control how fast Google crawls your site in Google Webmaster Tools](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/12/more-control-of-googlebots-crawl-rate.html).

> Crawl rate for your site determines
>   the time used by Googlebot to crawl
>   your site on each visit. Our goal is
>   to thoroughly crawl your site (so your
>   pages can be indexed and returned in
>   search results!) without creating a
>   noticeable impact on your server's
>   bandwidth. While most webmasters are
>   fine using the default crawl setting
>   (i.e. no changes needed, more on that
>   below), some webmasters may have more
>   specific needs.
>
> Googlebot employs sophisticated
>   algorithms that determine how much to
>   crawl each site it visits. For a vast
>   majority of sites, it's probably best
>   to choose the "Let Google determine my
>   crawl rate" option, which is the
>   default. However, if you're an
>   advanced user or if you're facing
>   bandwidth issues with your server, you
>   can customize your crawl rate to the
>   speed most optimal for your web
>   server(s). The custom crawl rate
>   option allows you to provide Googlebot
>   insight to the maximum number of
>   requests per second and the number of
>   seconds between requests that you feel
>   are best for your environment.
>
> Googlebot determines the range of
>   crawl rate values you'll have
>   available in Webmaster Tools. This is
>   based on our understanding of your
>   server's capabilities. This range may
>   vary from one site to another and
>   across time based on several factors.
>   Setting the crawl rate to a
>   lower-than-default value may affect
>   the coverage and freshness of your
>   site in Google's search results.
>   However, setting it to higher value
>   than the default won't improve your
>   coverage or ranking. If you do set a
>   custom crawl rate, the new rate will
>   be in effect for 90 days after which
>   it resets to Google's recommended
>   value.
>
> You may use this setting only for root
>   level sites and sites not hosted on a
>   large domain like blogspot.com (we
>   have special settings assigned for
>   them). To check the crawl rate
>   setting, sign in to Webmaster Tools
>   and visit the Settings tab. If you
>   have additional questions, visit the
>   Webmaster Help Center to learn more
>   about how Google crawls your site or
>   post your questions in the Webmaster
>   Help Forum.

Other then that you would probably need to create your own filtering system that sniffs out their user agents and either allows or denies search engine bots based in their user-agent. But that would only affect decreasing their frequency.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the second part of your question, you can tell Google using Webmaster Tools

> To change the crawl rate:
>
> 1. On the Webmaster Tools Home page,
>    click the site you want.
> 2. Under Site
>    configuration, click Settings.
> 3. In the
>    Crawl rate section, select the option
>    you want.

https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=48620&hl=en_GB

On the [Bing FAQ](http://www.bing.com/community/webmaster/f/12252/t/646805.aspx) it refers to [this post](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2008/06/03/robots-exclusion-protocol-joining-together-to-provide-better-documentation.aspx) which recommends setting `Crawl-Delay: X` where x is the number of seconds to wait between each request.

Of course sitemaps indicate how often pages change.