# How to know how regular the pages of itpian(dot) com are indexed by google?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, google-index

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I control how often search engines visit my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16067/how-do-i-control-how-often-search-engines-visit-my-site)

How to know how regular the pages of itpian(dot)com are indexed by google?

Answer (score 2):

Do a search for your site name using the "site:" operator: [`itpian site:itpian.com`](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=itpian%20site%3aitpian.com)