# How To Slow Down A Generic Bot?

Tags: web-crawlers

There is a generic bot (only identified as 'bot*') consuming most of my bandwidth and processing power. Blocking its IP stops it but since it comes from a well-known search-engine, I'd rather slow it down instead (it may be doing some useful experimental work). It's not the official crawler which actually visits my site a reasonable rate.

There is a [similar question for GoogleBot](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16067/how-do-i-control-how-often-search-engines-visit-my-site) which I have no problems with. The culprit takes 16X more bandwidth! **What I need though is a way to slow down a bot which is only distinguishable by IP. Is this possible?**

EDIT:

This is a Virtual Shared Host running Apache under Linux 64-bits with PHP 5.3.8. Although I have no direct control to the webserver, htaccess is enabled and I can have them add and configure modules on request.

Comment: This question is rather light on details. It would potentially be helpful to know which OS, http daemon, and application language you're using.

Comment: Good point! Edited the question with this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the tips in this discussion.
I think this can help you !

https://serverfault.com/questions/131364/apache-limit-the-number-of-requests-traffic-per-ip