# How to GEt Crawled Frequently

Tags: seo, crawl-rate

I wanted to know how to get crawled your Web Page Frequently to Different Search Enginges.

I want my Web to Get Crawled to Google Every Frequenct Day?
Can Anyone help me out.

Comment: Duplicate http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/16067/18400

Answer (score 0):

create accounts with google and bing webmasters. And implement your page. Then submit your page for crawling. This will defenately speed up the process. Otherwise you can just wait a few weeks until you get found and get frequently crawled.

**Google**
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=de
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?hl=en_uk&pli=1
**Bing**
http://www.bing.com/toolbox/submit-site-url
https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/submit-urls-to-bing-62f2860a

You also have to learn about other features of the webmaster tools.